# Embedding hyperbolic surfaces in $H^3$

Tags: manifolds, hyperbolic-geometry

All closed 2D manifolds except the sphere, torus, klein bottle, and projective plane are hyperbolic. Thus, e.g., the double torus is a hyperbolic manifold. However, when embedding a double torus in Euclidean space, it has obvious regions of positive curvature (just as an embedding regular torus has regions of positive curvature despite being a Euclidean manifold).

Meanwhile, if you embed a sphere in hyperbolic 3-space, it retains its inherent positive curvature.

So, is there a way to embed a double torus (or some other closed hyperbolic surface) into $H^3$ such that it has negative curvature everywhere?

If not, is there any other way to embed a closed hyperbolic $n$-manifold in a space of $n+1$ dimensions such that it retains negative curvature everywhere?

Comment: Put a sphere around the surface, and shrink the sphere until they're tangent. At the point where they touch, the surface has curvature greater than the sphere's, hence positive. This should work in hyperbolic space as well as Euclidean.

Comment: @mr_e_man Your argument is specific to the Euclidean setting where the ambient curvature vanishes. Here, the comparison between Gaussian curvature and extrinsic curvature will involve the ambient curvature of the hyperbolic space. Hence, it is not that sure that the argument always works

Comment: @Didier But the Gauss equation contribution of the ambient curvature will be the same, since the surfaces are tangent. I need to think through a proof, but I suspect the argument works.

Comment: @mr_e_man I guess we need to start by saying what we mean by sphere. I assume you intend a geodesic sphere?

Comment: @TedShifrin You're right. I should have a closer look at it.

Comment: @TedShifrin After a closer look, the argument works, but because geodesic spheres in the hyperbolic space have  positive principal curvatures **and** positive sectional curvatures (which is not the case, for instance, of small geodesic spheres in the complex hyperbolic space : they have some negatively curved tangent planes)